# How to import a triangle mesh into SketchUp with small faces?

Tags: file-io, import, sketchup

I'm trying to import a triangle mesh from file (e.g., .3ds, .dae). However, it seems that some of the faces (triangles) are being ignored. If I scale the model by 10x before importing, then the triangles are in tact. Is there a way to force sketchup to load all faces, even small ones?

Here's an example of loading a closed mesh (no boundaries) at its regular scale. SketchUp has ignored a few of the triangles, creating holes and dangling edges:
[image: a few missing triangles]

If I ***shrink*** the model, the problems are much worse:
[image: many problems]

But if I ***scale*** up the model enough, the problems go away:
[image: no problems]

*Also, immediately after I import my cursor is set to "move mode", so the object is placed wherever my cursor randomly happens to be. Is there a way to import the model exactly into the current coordinate system without mouse interaction?*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a known problem that Sketchup doesn't import very small edges/faces correctly. You can automate the import process of an upscaled model with this ruby script though:

```
model = Sketchup.active_model
# Import your dwg file, true if you want the summary screen
model.import 'C:\path\to\example.dwg', false

# Reset the selected tool
model.select_tool(nil)

# Get all imported faces
faces = model.entities.grep(Sketchup::Face)

# Create a new ComponentDefinition
definition = model.definitions.add "dwg"

# Add the points of every face to the definition  
faces.each{|f| definition.entities.add_face f.vertices}

# Remove all entities
model.entities.clear!

# Create a new DefinitionInstance that is scaled by 0.5
transformation = Geom::Transformation.new(0.5)
instance = model.entities.add_instance definition, transformation

# Explode the component to work with the model
instance.explode
```

This adds the component to the origin and takes care of scaling the imported model back. If your model were a `skp` file, you could even load it directly into a `ComponentDefinition`, but that doesn't work for `dwg` files.

Comment: Seems that `model.select_tool(nil)` cancels the import command. I'm on mac os x with sketchup version 16.1.1451

Comment: Hmm, too bad, works on my windows machine. What happens if you skip this line?

Comment: Then it's waiting for a mouse click to place the object.